# TemplateDoesNotExist when using Django package

Tags: python, django, templates

I followed this Django tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/reusable-apps/. 
I have a project called `oldcity` and an app called `oldantwerp`. The app is located in a parent directory called `django-oldantwerp` and the app directory itself has a subdirectory `templates`. The `index.html` file that my project is looking for is situated like so:

```
django-oldantwerp>oldantwerp>templates>oldantwerp>index.html
```

I tried to use this app with my project by including it in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'oldantwerp'
]
```

and in urls.py (in the projec), like so:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^oldantwerp/', include('oldantwerp.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

When I go to the admin page, everything works, but when I try to open the index page I get this error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /oldantwerp/
```

It says it tried to locate the index.html file like so:

```
Template loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
* django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /Users/Vincent/Apps/oldcity/templates/oldantwerp/index.html (Source does not exist)
* django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/Vincent/Apps/oldcity/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/oldantwerp/index.html (Source does not exist)
* django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/Vincent/Apps/oldcity/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/oldantwerp/index.html (Source does not exist)
```

And it also tried searching for another file: `place_list.html`, which is strange because I don't think I have such a file.

What could be wrong?

**EDIT**

This is the code of views.py in the oldantwerp folder:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'oldantwerp/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'places'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Place.objects.order_by('id')[:]
```

**EDIT**

Maybe worth mentioning: it all did work when I just had a folder `oldantwerp` as a subdirectory in the `oldicty` project folder. This error only occurred after I started implementing it from an external package.

**EDIT**

These are my template settings in settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

Comment: please give us your views...

Comment: I edited it in there.

Comment: Did you remember to include your templates in the manifest file (step 6) in [the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/reusable-apps/)? If you type `import oldantwerp; print(oldantwerp.__file__)` to your code, what path does it show?

Comment: The template name `place_list.html` would be the default for a **List**View for the **Place** model. Once you set `template_name`, it shouldn't search for `place_list.html` any more.

Comment: Yes I have included the manifest file like in the tutorial. When I type `print(oldantwerp.__file__)` in the shell I get this: `/Users/Vincent/Apps/oldcity/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/oldantwerp/__init__.py`

Comment: I have set template_name to ''oldantwerp/index.html", do you think this is incorrect?

Comment: hey i was facing the same issue when i build a package and reused my app, the reason behind was that when i moved my application directory in another one. Not knowingly the paths of views were changed. So before building your application make sure that your views can be located properly. e-g 'polls/detail.html' was rewritten 'polls/templates/polls/detail.html'. So, go and check the paths to your template files and build after that.

Answer (score 0):

One most likely problem could be you have got the template name wrong in your view. Ensure you use the template `oldantwerp/index.html` in the view, not just `index.html`.

Comment: I edited the question and I was indeed using oldantwerp/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your stacktrace you will see that you application tries to load the template from: `* django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /Users/Vincent/Apps/oldcity/templates/oldantwerp/index.html (Source does not exist).`
If I read your first statement correctly your directory structure is:

```
django-oldantwerp>oldantwerp>templates>oldantwerp>index.html.
```

So you can either create a directory structure proper for django to identify your templates directory or you can update your templates constant from the settings file and point django to a physical location where it can find your templates.

Comment: The difference between those two paths is that the first one tries to find index.html in de oldcity (project) folder while the actual templates folder is located in the django-oldantwerp package. I don't think it's a good idea to store templates for an app in de the project folder itself...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set DIRS in settings.py like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), delete the oldantwerp folder from your templates folder and add index.html in templates.

After that, edit  template_name = 'oldantwerp/index.html' to  template_name = 'index.html'

Comment: is APP_DIRS set to True?

Comment: You can do one more thing, do you use Pycharm?

Comment: Yes it is set to True. I'll edit in my template settings.

Comment: And I don't use Pycharm.

Comment: you can try right click on templates and mark folder as template folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135387/discussion-between-nita-alexandru-and-vincent).